# Run over someone

Tags: grammar

Do this phrase mean to insult, defeat verbally? figuratively I mean kinda like "go hard at someone"

I found it on Green’s Dictionary it says "*to harass verbally, to tease; thus running n., teasing, scolding*", but I can't understand if it's possible to say meaning so

My example

> He ran over all of his critics in his new interview.
>
> He ran over his haters in his last freestyle

Edited

Comment: "Steamroll" (used figuratively) is a possible synonym for "to run over."

Comment: @Era - in my experience (UK) the verb is 'to steamroller' - steamroller verb [ T ]  informal to use great force either to make someone do something or on something to make it happen or be successful: He steamrollered the plan through the committee. I hate being steamrollered into doing something I don't want to. (Cambridge)

Comment: Ah, I see - it's a dictionary _of slang_.  The definition you quote is for _run_; there is a separate entry for _run over_ which says 'to treat contemptuously, to victimize; to defeat'. The examples include " I would not advise any man to try to run over me ." (1847) and some others referring to defeating a sports team. It's American, and not familiar to me as a British English speaker.

Comment: What is your concern? With the meaning, whether people are familiar with it, appropriate register, any regional/national limitations, politeness? Just because something's in Green's, that doesn't mean it's current or common; often it means the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

This is not current slang.

In modern use "run {someone} over" means to hit them with a car.  Greens [has no examples from the last 35 years](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/ggv7sfi#kfxxnca), and the most recent examples might be the car sense being used metaphorically, instead of the sense of "treat contemptuously".

Your examples would not be understood by most people today.

Comment: So what would fit best in this case?